# Dificuldade para passar coluna no filter_by como parâmetro na função Python3 com SQLAlchemt

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Estou usando SQLAlchemy para trabalhar com tabelas de banco de dados.
Estou criando classes para as devidas tabelas, onde tenho como métodos dessas classes, insert, filter_all(), etc.

Estou usando a seguinte classe com seus métodos:

```
class Veiculos(base):
    __tablename__ = "veiculos"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, autoincrement=True)
    marca =  Column(String(20))
    modelo = Column(String(20))
    ano = Column(Integer)

    def __init__(self, str_marca="None", str_modelo="None", int_ano="None"):
        """
        :param str_marca: (str).
        :param str_modelo: (str).
        :param  int_ano: (int).
        """
        self.marca =  str_marca
        self.modelo = str_modelo
        self.ano = int_ano

    def __repr__(self):
        return "< Veículo {}, {}, {} >".format(self.marca, self.modelo, self.ano)

    def insert(self):
        session.add(self)
        session.commit()

    @classmethod
    def find_by_column(self, session, str_column, var_search):
        search = var_search
        coluna = str_column
        return  session.query(self).filter_by(self.coluna=search).all()

    @classmethod
    def select_all(self, session):        
        return session.query(self)
```

Meu problema está nesse método:

```
def find_by_column(self, session, str_column, var_search):
            search = var_search
            coluna = str_column
            return  session.query(self).filter_by(self.coluna=search).all()
```

Onde gostaria de passar o nome da coluna e o valor para busca tudo nos parâmetros da função.

O que estou fazendo de errado?

Comment: Por que não usa o [filter_by](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by)? Pode aplicar a coluna que quiser sem ter que ficar rescrevendo o método no modelo, `session.query(MyClasse).filter_by(meu_campo = 'valor')`

Comment: @gato acredito que você não prestou atenção no meu código.
Estou usando filter_by. A questão é que não queria passar o nome do campo diretamente no filter_by, e sim por parâmetro na chamada da função.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagino que isto `.filter_by(self.coluna=search)` esteja causando o seguinte erro:

```
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

No caso me parece que você quer passar o valor da chave, que é um "parâmetro dinâmico", neste caso você pode usar o `unpack`:

- https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists

exemplo mais simples para entender:

```
def filter_by(**kwargs):
    print('keys', kwargs.keys())
    print('values', kwargs.values())

filter_by(teste=1)

minha_coluna = 'teste2'

filter_by(**{ minha_coluna: 'Hello' })
```

O nome do argumento passado assim pode ser dinamico, veja um exemplo semelhante a sua classe:

```
class Teste:
    coluna = 'teste'

    def filter_by(self, **kwargs):
        print('keys', kwargs.keys())
        print('values', kwargs.values())
        print('-----')

    def exec(self):
        #manualmente
        self.filter_by(teste=1)

        #dinamicamente
        self.filter_by(**{self.coluna: 1})

foo = Teste()
foo.exec()
```

Então para resolver provavelmente deve ficar assim:

```
session.query(self).filter_by(**{self.coluna: search}).all()
```

Eu não pude testar, mas pela documentação https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/query.html#sqlalchemy.orm.query.Query.filter_by a função usa mesmo `**kwargs` (provavelmente nem teria como fazer de outra forma), então se falhar em algo me avise.

Exemplo online para testar no [**repl.it**](https://repl.it/@inphinit/unpacking-key-arg)

Comment: Muito obrigado pela dica. Resolveu meu problema, pois não queria fazer um filter para cada atributo.

Comment: @CleberNandi só pra constar, na sua classe não tem `coluna`, você fez isso `coluna = str_column`, mas creio q seria isso o desejado `this.coluna = str_column`, mas só estou comentando, de qualquer forma o problema principal era "o **nome** do parametro de forma dinamica"